# excel macro open on row specified in cell

Tags: excel, macros, cell

I've specified in cell "B1" where my sheet needs to be opened on (=MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0)).

And I want to automatically open my excel sheet on that row. 
(example: row 10 = today)

or can I use the function "=today()" in VBA ?

I'm kind of a noob in VBA so can you please assist me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following Event Macro in the ***worksheet code area:***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Cells(Range("B1").Value, "A").Select
End Sub
```

When the worksheet is opened, the proper cell will automatically be `Selected`:

[image]

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**
**EDIT#1:**

To get the same behavior when the file is opened, leave the previous macro in place and put this macro in the ***workbook code area:***

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Cells(Range("B1").Value, "A").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*(you would replace Sheet1 with the name of your worksheet)*

Comment: can this be done on opening of the complete file too ? instead of only when changing sheets ?

Comment: @DennisLaan  See my **EDIT#1**